# Обертка COM модуля на С++ для использования в .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, c++-cli, com, activex

Добрый день, имеется библиотека написанная на С++ и реализующая ActiveX контрол. Возникла задача использовать этот компонент в WPF приложении. Предположительно использовать C++/CLI для создания обертки, но поскольку я с ним знаком слабо возникли сложности как грамотно это реализовать. Непосредственное подключение данной библиотеки через COM возможно, но именно от него мы и хотим уйти.  Также желательно получить непосредственно WPF контрол в C++ библиотеке, чтобы не использовать кучу вспомогательных контейнеров для ActiveX.

P.S. Я изучал подход, описанный в инструкции Microsoft "Hosting an ActiveX Control in WPF" и он работает. Но у меня вопрос насколько сильно и в какую сторону нужно копать, чтобы изменить код на C++ контрола ActiveX , в код C++/CLI  контрола WPF и использовать его напрямую без COM Interop?

Comment: Э... а почему непосредственное подключение через COM вас не устраивает?

Comment: Нет особой разницы, к чему подключать COM-компоненту: к проекту на C# или обёртке на C++/CLI. В любом случае вам будет нужен инсталлятор или SXS-манифест.